# Pulling out specifc numbers from an array using C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to pull out specific numbers from an array. Basically I get a file that is like this:

Array: 13 10

Length: 4

What I did is I read the file character by character and stored it in an array. I don't know how to pull out the digits from the array. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
  char ar_ch[200];
  int i = 0;
  char ch;
  FILE* file = fopen("array.txt","r");
  if(file == NULL)
  {
    perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
  {
    ar_ch[i]=ch;
    i++;
  }
  ar_ch[i]='\0';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ch` needs to be `int`, not `char`, otherwise you will not be able to reliably detect `EOF`.

Comment: use `strtok` -> `strtol` etc.etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have filled `ar_ch` correctly, loop through `ar_ch` and test each value. Use functions like [`isdigit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) and [`isalpha()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) (note that these take in `int` values, not `char` values) to test the type of value and process according to your needs.